# Android Studio null object reference when creating

Tags: java, android

I am creating the class object before using it to set a variable in the class but I still get the null reference error. Why is this happeing?

```
public void onCreate() {
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if(ma.isWalking) {
                    Log.i("walk","walking");
                }
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Are you creating tbe object of an Actual Activity? I don't think you can directly create an instance of a subclass of an Android Activity class

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is used for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely positively cannot create an `Activity` like this:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
```

Only the Android framework can instantiate Android components (`Activity`, `Service`, etc.)

Just use `public static` variables for this purpose which can be accessed from any class.